# React-Query: Invalidate query for specific id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

### Summarize Problem:

I'm trying to invalidate my `GET` query for making a request to fetch a single user. Since there are many users, I have to 2 query keys on my `GET` request, `fetch-user` and `id`:

```js
useQuery<User, AxiosError>(['fetch-user', id], () => fetchUser(id));
```

Whenever I `PATCH` the user I want to invalidate said request, otherwise the previous (cached) values are shown rather than the updated ones.

**How do I invalidate a query with a specific key, in my case `fetch-user` and an additional key of the `id`?**

### Show some code:

Hook for `GET` user with specific id:

```js
const fetchUser = (id: number): Promise<User> => {
  return axios.get(`/users/${id}`).then((resp) => resp.data);
};
export const useUserData = (id: number) => {
  return useQuery<User, AxiosError>(['fetch-user', id], () => fetchUser(id));
};
```

Hook for `PATCH` user with specific id:

```js
const patchUser = (id: number, body: PatchUser): Promise<User> => {
  return axios
    .patch(`/users/${id}`, body, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/merge-patch+json' } })
    .then((resp) => resp.data);
};
export const useUpdateUserData = (id: number, onSuccess: (body: User) => void) => {
  return useMutation<User, AxiosError, PatchUser>((variables) => patchUser(id, variables), {
    onSuccess
  });
};
```

Using react-query in my page:

```js
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const {
    data: user,
    isLoading: isUserGetLoading,
    isSuccess: isUserGetSuccessful
  } = useUserData(Number(id));

  const OnSuccess = (body: User) => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(['fetch-user', 'fetch-all-users']);
  };

  const {
    mutate: updateUser,
    isLoading: isUserPatchLoading,
    isError: isUserPatchError,
    error: userPatchError
  } = useUpdateUserData(Number(id), OnSuccess);
```

### What I've tried:

##### 1. Passing an empty `invalidateQueries`

```js
queryClient.invalidateQueries();
```

It works! But all queries are invalidated rather than the specific one I want to invalidate. So this is not an option.

##### 2. Passing the id as a parameter

```js
queryClient.invalidateQueries(['fetch-user', id, 'fetch-all-users']);
```

Doesn't invalidate the query.

##### 3. Passing the id as a parameter and grouping it to `fetch-user`

```js
queryClient.invalidateQueries([['fetch-user', id], 'fetch-all-users']);
```

Doesn't invalidate the query.

### Workarounds:

I can change the key of the `GET` query to contain the id, such as:

```js
export const useUserData = (id: number) => {
  return useQuery<User, AxiosError>([`fetch-user-${id}`], () => fetchUser(id));
};
```

And then I can invalidate it as:

```js
const OnSuccess = (body: User) => {
  queryClient.invalidateQueries([`fetch-user-${id}`, 'fetch-all-users']);
};
```

However, I'd like to avoid this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `invalidateQueries` for each query you'd like to invalidate.

```js
  const OnSuccess = (body: User) => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(['fetch-user']);
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(['fetch-all-users']);
  };
```